# How can I win a game of battle royale in hole.io when both my opponent and I have maxed out our hole size?

Tags: hole.io

I'm playing hole.io in Battle Royale mode. Before I managed to kill off my last opponent, they maxed out their hole size. Now the both of us are at Level 19 and just wandering around the map which continually respawns. We can't eat each other because we're the same size. Is this a stalemate? Is there any way to end the game without quitting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug that causes the game to break. You can neither win or lose at that point and your only way out is to quit / force-close the app. This bug has been reported on Reddit multiple times.

Before the update that broke it, you could reach level 20. The game would end when all living players reached level 20, placing them all on 1st place.

What you can do until they fix this bug:

- Make sure nobody else reaches level 19.
- If someone does, let them eat you before you reach level 19; 2nd place is better than closing the app and losing all progress from that game.